# How to return id from Insert with libpqtype

Tags: c, postgresql

I have a c script which writes incoming aircraft data to a postgres db.
I would like to return the new records ID after the INSERT but am having trouble.

The simplified code is like this:

```
int new_id;
conn = PQconnectdb("dbname = flight_dev");
PQinitTypes(conn);
PGresult *res = PQexecf(conn,"INSERT INTO aircrafts (hex) VALUES (%text)", aircraft_hex);
PQgetf(res, 0, "%int4", 0, &new_id);
```

The INSERT is successful however new_id is not assigned and gives the error "row number 1 is out of range 0..-1"

Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: `INSERT ... RETURNING`.

Answer (score 3):

use `INSERT INTO aircrafts (hex) VALUES (%text) RETURNING id` to return the id column of the newly inserted row

Answer (score 2):

I had been missing the semicolon when previously using RETURNING id

```
PGresult *res = PQexecf(conn,"INSERT INTO aircrafts (hex) VALUES (%text) RETURNING ID;", aircraft_hex);
```